# mysql to select all from one table inner join with another table on some condition fails

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.* FROM works AS a WHERE a.userid=15 INNER JOIN users AS b ON a.userid=b.id;
```

Something is just wrong and I don't know why, someone could offer some help please ? Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Your `WHERE` clause is in the wrong position.  It always follows all tables listed and joined in the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM
   works AS a
   INNER JOIN users AS b ON a.userid=b.id
WHERE a.userid=15 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT a.* FROM works a INNER JOIN users b ON a.userid=b.id WHERE a.userid=15;
```

the WHERE, ORDER/GROUP BY clauses should be placed at the end of the query (unless it is in a sub query then it would be at the end of the sub-query)